# How to get toggled() signal working with a QPushButton?

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I have the follwing code where `moreButton` is a `QPushButton`. When I toggle the button, nothing happens.

Shouldn't it show or hide `secondaryGroupBox` and `tertiaryGroupBox`?

```
QObject::connect(moreButton, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), secondaryGroupBox, SLOT(setVisible(bool)));
QObject::connect(moreButton, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), tertiaryGroupBox, SLOT(setVisible(bool)));
```

Comment: Related to [pyQt: radioButton.isChecked() is executed twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808257/pyqt-radiobutton-ischecked-is-executed-twice)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most likely, your pushbutton is not `checkable()`. Try

```
moreButton->setCheckable(true)
```

A non-checkable button never emits the `toggled(bool)` signal.